# How to add date query sting and not time

Tags: .htaccess

htaccess that will add a timestamp at end of url

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME} [L,R=302,NE]
```

now url is

```
http://example.com/page1.html?20150219190231    
(year,month date - hour - minutes - seconds)
```

i like url to be just like this

```
http://example.com/page1.html?20150219
(Year , month ,date)
```

i try adding  ?%{Date} but that dont work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: you can't just make up your own `%` variables. There's a set list of what's available: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond   you'll have to make up your own from TIME_YEAR, TIME_MON, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MONTH}%{TIME_DAY} [L,R=302,NE]
```